# Programming a custom made STM32 board via USB

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, pcb-design, usb, stm32

[image]I've designed a custom board using STM32g431cb for a project recently.
My goal was to be able to program the board via both stlink and the usb port depending on the preference. I used the USB_DP and USB_DM ports that the CUBEIDE gave me. I can program the board using ST-Link without a problem but the USB doesn't seems to work. My computer can supply the board but it doesn't see the port to program it.

Now, I'm very new to this and I've read many applicaiton notes (tried to figure out reading [AN4879 USB hardware and PCB guidelines using STM32 MCUs](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00296349-usb-hardware-and-pcb-guidelines-using-stm32-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) - STM32G4 models can't be found there) but I really can't wrap my head around this debugging thing since there is really many of them.

The thing is, I get really confused when it comes to debugging/programming stuff. Should I do something extra if I want to program it via using the USB directly by plugging in? Should I add an FTDI or another converter to my board to use the port?

Sorry If it sounds too newbie-ish. I can take any help from application note recs or explanations. The sources for stm32g4 are not as common as the sm32f series so it's harder for me to process it.

Comment: How do you put the MCU in DFU mode? Post the schematics to see what's wrong.

Comment: @Justme I've edited it. This is the schematic of my former circuit using stm32f103 series. I'll use fdcan ports of the g series so I I'll make a few changes after this one.  I can't use the usb in both of them anyway.

Comment: You say G431 but in the schematics there is F103. Big difference.

Comment: I suppose you change Boot0 for programming? I have a STM32G441 project here and that enumerates just fine for DFU mode - if you flip Boot0.

Comment: Are you sure the R2 is not the problem?

Comment: Yes I change the boot0 manually. Also I've made the explanation about the f103 after I upload the schematic. f103 doesn't upload the code either unfortunately. the reason I used a pull-up resistor for the usb port is because I read an instruction in the usb application notes of the STMicroelectronics. Do you think it is the problem?

Comment: doesnt the documentation say that it requires an external 8mhz oscillator/crystal?

Comment: and  btw dont use the blue pill as a reference for the f103 it has known issues with the pcie interface, I didnt look that close at your schematic

Comment: the newer parts are super easy no extra components, just hook up the usb directly.  but you still have to control the boot pin(s)...

Comment: Well, on F103 you need the resistor. But connecting it directly to 3.3V may not be wise. The F103 also has no DFU support, so it can't be programmed via USB, not unless you first program it with a USB bootloader that makes it possible.